# How how many options are there to put the letters AAAABBBBCCCC (4 A, 4 B, 4 C) in a word so that there are at least 2 A next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

how many option there are to put the letters AAAABBBBCCCC (4 A, 4 B, 4 C) in a word so that there are 2 A next to each other? 
for example AAAABBBBCCCC counts as an option.
is there a way to think about it as a problem with cells and balls? without Inclusion-Exclusion Principle ?

Attempt:  The number of arrangements of the letters AAAABBBBCCCC with no restrictions is $\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}$.

Comment: You can find the number of arrangements with at least two $A$s next to each other by subtractingthe number of arrangements with no two $A$s next to each other from the total number of arrangements.  What have you attempted and where are you stuck?  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: how can I solve it in the wat you suggest?

Comment: Again, what have you attempted and where are you stuck?

Comment: how can I count the case of "no two As next to each other from the total number of arrangements"?without Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Comment: Do you know how to count the total number of distinguishable arrangements of the letters in the string $AAAABBBBCCCC$?  If so, you should include that calculation or at least your attempt in your question.  If you can show me that, I will answer your question.

Comment: yes :(12 choose 4)*(8 choose 4)*(4 choose 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly calculated, there are $\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}$ ways to arrange the letters $AAAABBBBCCCC$ without restriction.  From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which no two $A$s are adjacent.  To do so, we first arrange the letters $BBBBCCCC$, which can be done in $\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}$ ways.  This creates nine spaces, seven between successive letters and two at the ends of the row where we can place the $A$s.
$$\square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square L \square$$
where each $L$ represents one of the eight letters in the string $BBBBCCCC$.  To ensure that no two $A$s are adjacent, we must select four of these nine spaces in which to place the $A$s.  Hence, there are $\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}\binom{9}{4}$ arrangements in which no two $A$s are adjacent.  Thus, the number of admissible arrangements is
$$\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4} - \binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}\binom{9}{4}$$

Comment: I really like this way of thinking!didnt think about it! thank you I appreciate it